# Sort a sorted nested list by another index

Tags: python, list, sorting

How can I sort an already sorted list by another index?

example: I have a list that is sorted by index 1.

```
[["DOG", 5], ["DAM",5], ["DAN", 5], ["BAT", 4], ["CAT", 3], ["MAN", 2]]
```

I want the following output:

```
[["DAM", 5], ["DAN",5], ["DOG", 5], ["BAT", 4], ["CAT", 3], ["MAN", 2]]
```

The list has been sorted by index 1. If an index 1 has multiple occurences in the list, how should I sort index 0 so that the overall nested list retains its order in terms of index 0?

Comment: What language...

Comment: language is python, sorry

Comment: I think the question needs more clarification... what do you mean by index 1? index 1 is a list..

Comment: Why is it already sorted by index 1? Maybe you could instead sort it like you want here right away?

Comment: @Justsomeone Index 1 is the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct custom key function that returns 2-item tuples (first second element (negative) and then first element):

```py
lst = [["DOG", 5], ["DAM", 5], ["DAN", 5], ["BAT", 4], ["CAT", 3], ["MAN", 2]]

print(sorted(lst, key=lambda k: (-k[1], k[0])))
```

Prints:

```
[["DAM", 5], ["DAN", 5], ["DOG", 5], ["BAT", 4], ["CAT", 3], ["MAN", 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the list has been sorted once, you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, chain
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(sorted(group) for _, group in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(1))))
[['DAM', 5], ['DAN', 5], ['DOG', 5], ['BAT', 4], ['CAT', 3], ['MAN', 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean. But, you can always sort a list based on a key.

```
l = ['ali', 'mohamed', 'ahmed']
l.sort(key = lambda char: char[2])   # this will sort the list based on the 
                                      #charachter at index 2
```

output: `['mohamed', 'ali', 'ahmed']`

You can also sort the list in descending or ascending order.

```
l.sort(key = lambda char: char[2], reverse = True)
```

output: `['ahmed', 'ali', 'mohamed']`

Comment: This is not what he means. He means to sort by multiple criteria. First the second index in reverse, then the first one not in reverse.